# HDRI showing in reflection. How to remove?

Tags: rendering, hdri, reflection, filmic-blender

So I Have my transparency turned on in film however my HDRI is showing in reflections. How do I Fix this so the HDRI does not show in reflections of materials!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The whole point of HDRIs is to show in reflections and influence scene lighting. You can always remove it.

Comment: you can increase roughness of your material, then it won't reflect anymore.